# Capybara Selenium Chrome opens About Google Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara, google-chrome-headless

I have an issue with testing in Chrome. When I run the test it opens the chrome://settings/help page in a new tab. This causes my tests to fail as it can't find the buttons it should click on. I was debugging in Chrome in normal mode when I saw what happend.

Can I prevent this from happening? Or can I keep the tab where I'm testing in focussed in some way?

Comment: Do you want to test Chrome's help page and the problem is that it opens in another tab? Or is the problem that the help page opens at all? Is it a Capybara or a Chrome issue? Does the same thing happen when you open Chrome manually with the same options as Capybara does?

Comment: The problem is that it opens at all. This tab becomes focussed instead of the tab I'm testing in. I'm not sure what causes this to happen. It does not happen when I open Chrome manually with the same options.

Comment: This test had worked before. I did not change it for months btw.

Comment: I ran into the same issue as you, it looks like it is working fine with Chrome 61, but something has changed in Chrome 62. Still looking for a fix

Comment: Same issue, however I attributed it to having disabled Keystone Agent since I didn't want Chrome being updated in the background. Turned out Chrome had already been updated to 62, while chromedriver remained at 2.29.461585.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into the same issue this morning. All our tests were failing because `chrome://settings/help` was automatically opened when we ran our selenium tests.

This behaviour did not happen when we used Chrome 61, and suddenly appeared when it got updated to Chrome 62.

In order to fix that we had to update the `chromedriver` binary to the latest version. You can find the drivers on here https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Our tests are now running normally again.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I've updated the driver and now that tab is not opened anymore.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Germain's comment, since I had a hard time remembering how to update the chromedriver -- I'm on a mac and originally installed it using brew, so now I had to do a 'brew upgrade chromedriver'.  Also probably a good idea to restart spring if you're using that for your tests.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone using this [chromedriver-helper](https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper). Then update the `chromedriver` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper#updating-to-latest-chromedriver). I updated to **2.33** and error is solved.