# ChromeDriver ver. 2.31 opening About Chrome page in Google Chrome ver. 62.0.3202.94 on Mac (python)

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, splinter

ChromeDriver ver. 2.31 opening About Chrome page in Google Chrome ver. 62.0.3202.94 on Mac OS X Yosemite (python + splinter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Updating the ChromeDrive manually from v2.31 to v2.33 from  https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html solved the problem.
Or if you use brew just execute:

```
brew upgrade chromedriver
```

To check you ChromeDriver version on Mac OSX Yosemite run the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
print "google ChromeDriver version: %s" % driver.capabilities['chrome']['chromedriverVersion']
```

See also: [Capybara Selenium Chrome opens About Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805148/capybara-selenium-chrome-opens-about-google-chrome)